# Python based exe throwing error at CMD (pynput module)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pynput

So this is the error it's throwing in cmd windows 10. Seems to be something to do with pynput? Not really sure what I can do to fix this and appreciate any help.

```
C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\herprogram\dist\beeb>beeb.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\herprogram\beeb.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pynput
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend
ImportError
[11880] Failed to execute script beeb
```

Many thanks

Comment: try to use version 1.6.8 of pynput if it has the features you need, pynput==1.6.8

Comment: is this command to be used with pyinstaller via cmd? thanks

Comment: with which command do you make your app?

Comment: I just run pyinstaller file.exe in powershell

Comment: How do you include pynput or any other libraries with your exe?

Comment: I thought pyinstaller did it automatically? It doesn't seem to have a problem with the other modules.

Comment: okay, try to run `pyinstaller --hidden-import=pynput==1.6.8; file.py`

Comment: I see the logic but unfortunately it does not work. I get the same result. There is also some information about extending the path which I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Is it possible pynput is not a supported pyinstaller module? I don't see it on the list here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages

Comment: it is possible :(, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239618/codekeylogger-converted-into-exe-with-pyinstaller-not-working-as-it-was

Comment: Yea it looks like those guys were having issues with it as well. I guess I'll remove it from the program and try a workaround. Thanks for all your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: yup, the best you can do is to try py-to-exe for windows, and py-to-app for mac :(

Answer (score 1):

I switched to a different module pywinauto which is officially supported by pyinstaller and used:

```
import pywinauto
pywinauto.mouse.double_click(button='left', coords=(0, 0))
```

This solved the issue. Thanks guys